# Adding items with the Isotope for Wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

Tricky one here (I think).. I'm using the [Isotope For Wordpress](http://mintthemes.com/isotope-for-wordpress/) plugin to pull my posts into an isotope grid. All works perfectly except I've been unable to get any of the [Adding Methods](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html) to work. Here is what I'm trying (with the goal of adding three new posts to the grid):

```
var $container = $('.mintthemes_isotopes_container');
var $items = $('<div class="hentry" /> <div class="hentry" /> <div class="hentry" />');

 $('#insert').click(function() {
    $('.mintthemes_isotopes_container').isotope( 'insert', $items );    
 });

$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
$container.isotope({
  animationEngine: 'best available',
    transformsEnabled: true,
    itemSelector: '.hentry', 
     masonry: {
     columnWidth: 1,
     gutterWidth: 5
    },
});
```

I think my problem lies in what im defining what the $items to be. The code above adds three new containers, styled correctly, but there's no content. I think i need to call the actual posts instead of the ".hentry" but I'm not sure how to do that within that .js file that the plugin provided. Here's how the posts are called in my index.php:

```
<?php mintthemes_isotopes(); ?>

<?php
          // Blog post query
$linksPosts = new WP_Query();
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged'=>$paged, 'showposts'=>3) );
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

<div <?php post_class(); ?>>

<div class=".mintthemes_isotopes_container">
<div class=".isotope-item">

<p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();</p></a>

 </div>  <!-- /isotope item -->
 </div>  <!--/.mintthemes_isotopes_container-->
 </div>   <!-- /.post_class -->

 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I can't call that php post_class(); in an external .js file right? Is there any other way I can call these posts? Any and all ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily insert more elements - as you did. The part that won't work is adding an element that doesn't exist on the page.

For a WordPress post to 'exist' on the page, it has to be queried by PHP in some way.

You can use a custom query - like you did using WP_Query():
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

You can also use something like get_posts:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

But unless you queried them through WP somehow, they don't exist on the page and can't be added at runtime.

You could do a separate query for the extra posts you want and put them in a div with the CSS set to display:none

That way, you could reference them with your JS because they would exist on the page.

Something like this:

```
global $post;

//First Query
$args = array(
   'post_type' => "post",
   'tax_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
        'taxonomy' =>  'category',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => 'my_category_name,
        'operator' => 'IN'
       )
     )            
);

$posts_main_group = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts_main_group as $post) : 
     ?><div class="<?php post_class(); ?>" style="block;"><?php the_title(); ?></div><?php
endforeach;

//Second hidden query
$args = array(
   'post_type' => "post",
   'tax_query' => array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
        'taxonomy' =>  'category',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => 'my_hidden_category_name_with_extra_posts,
        'operator' => 'IN'
       )
     )            
);

$posts_extra_group = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts_extra_group as $post) : 
     ?><div class="<?php post_class(); ?>" style="display:none;"><?php the_title(); ?></div><?php
endforeach;
```

This way, you can target the hidden divs with jquery and add them - now that they exist on the page.

Also note, I did the CSS inline for simplicity's sake in the example - but you should use a stylesheet to do that if possible.